# Is std::vector::end()[-1] a undefined behavior?

Tags: c++

```cpp
std::vector v { 1, 2, 3, 4, };
```

The `v.end()[-1]` is able to access element 4.

For a long<sub>about 2 years</sub> time, I use `*(v.rbegin() + 0)`...

Will it cause any problems if I only use indexes ranged on `[-static_cast<int>(v.size()), -1]`?

Comment: What if `operator[]` of `std::vector<int>::iterator` takes a `std::size_t` instead of an `int`?

Comment: Looks fine to me, (`operator[]` for a vector iterator takes `ptrdiff_t` BTW)

Comment: What's wrong with `v.back()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are allowed to use the subscript operator on a [*LegacyRandomAccessIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator).

```
i[n]    convertible to reference    *(i + n)
```

where `n` is of type `std::iterator_traits<It>::difference_type` (which is signed).

So, as long as you stay within the valid bounds, it's fine.

```
int main() {
    std::vector v { 1, 2, 3, 4, };

    for(auto i = -static_cast<std::ptrdiff_t>(v.size()); i < 0; ++i) {
        std::cout << v.end()[i] << '\n';
    }
}
```

The cast may overflow though.

Answer (score 2):

`v.end()[-1]` for a non-empty vector is fine and accesses the last element.

And yes you can extend this to indexes in the range `[-static_cast<int>(v.size()), -1]`.

But in general my preference would be to use reverse iterators if you want to iterate backwards through a vector. That's what they are designed for.

Answer (score 2):

That's just a more confusing way of spelling:

```
v.back();
```

And if you want n-th element from the back, just do:

```
v[v.size() - n];
```

Everyone understands what this does unambiguously.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I don't think to make `v.size()` **minus** `int` is 100% safe.

Comment: @TicTirol It is just as safe as `v.end()[-n]` -- both cause UB if n is larger than the size.

Comment: And there can be difficulties if the size of the vector > 2^31

Comment: @Sebastian no, not at all. Check it out: https://godbolt.org/z/M9obanPcT

Comment: You're right. I did many mistakes on it, like `::std::string s{"123"}` and I use `for (int i = 0; i < s.size() - 4; i += 1)` That's so silly that it caused a <i>long-time</i> loop. That's why I mention that.

Comment: @TicTirol Well, that's a different use case. In that case, you can use `ssize(s)` starting with C++20, which returns a signed integer.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Switch to msvc on godbolt and it fails to compile.

Comment: @Sebastian [it doesn't](https://godbolt.org/z/ef7dacfza). Maybe you accidentally picked the 32 bit version.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili You are right, I accidentally picked the 32 bit version with a different `SIZE_MAX`, so the static_assert line (with the hardcoded ULL numbers) failed, because of that.